# How to delete all cashed data depending upon old commits?

Tags: nuxt.js, local-storage, vuex

I'm developing an e-commerce app built with **Nuxtjs**, The app have a cart stored at `localstorage`, but currently I've changed how adding to cart is handled, how data is displayed (*backend and frontend*) and how we handle quantity and removing from cart and everything, which will cause errors at some scenarios.

What I'm afraid of is after I push the new code if the user has any items in the cart he won't be able to deal with it at anyway, and he will get errors even when opens the cart -*because as I said cart-item properties has changed*-, so I'm thinking of clearing the storage and vuex store to make the user add items with the new code and everything, but how can I make sure that the user who is trying to open the app we actually cleared localstorage for him before?

**Is there a better way to handle this context?**

Comment: This isn't a version-control issue at all, it's a question of how to decide whether cached data should be invalidated. To do that, use a "data format version number" or similar and change it when the data-format version changes.

Comment: Hi @torek thank you for replying, Could ypu please refer an article or something to help me out with that?, I really don't know what `data-format version` means

Comment: It means that, for instance, you'd store in your cache data a number: `version=1` for instance. Then when you change what goes in the cache, you increment the number. When you *read* the cached data, you inspect the number: if it's out of date (doesn't match the *current* number hardcoded in the source) you know the cache data is no longer valid. In more complex systems such as databases, you'd have a version number and a *migration* system to upgrade the old version to the new.

Comment: you mean I should add a key in localstorage with version number and when deploying new version I should update that version number an remove the old cache data? Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, or change a property name (see [Kapcash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72601694/1256452)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem of invalidating deprecated / old version cached data.

There is no need to clear the Vuex store. This store only lives in a user session, it's not persisted. As soon as the tab is closed, the vuex store is lost. And until the user doesn't refresh its tab, it won't have the new code.

You just have to care about the persisted data (here: the items in localStorage).

You have two ways to handle this:

1. The cached data isn't critical and you can delete it entirely.
2. The cached data is important and must be migrated to the new format.

*It's up to you to choose which one you want to implement.*

For both, the technical solution can be the same: create a Nuxt client-side plugin to update the cached data.

> **Example**:
> Bob has some items in its localStorage, stored in format #1.
> Bob goes to the updated website:
>
> 1. nuxt loads the plugins.
> 2. your cache invalidation plugin removes / migrate to format #2 the old cached data
> 3. the Vue app loads
> 4. the cart component is mounted and there is no problem because the localStorage is already up to date.

```js
// plugins/cacheInvalidator.client.js
export default const cacheInvalidatorPlugin = (context) => {
  const cachedCart = localStorage.getItem('cart');
   // the way you identify that the stored cart is the old one.
  const isOldCart = 'oldProperty' in cachedCart;
  if (isOldCart) {
    localStorage.removeItem('cart');
    // or transform the old one to the new format and update it in localStorage
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much for replying, Yeah that's what I came up with and I already implemented the solution of reformatting the persisted data in localStorage.